# GORM get/find resource by ID using MongoDB in Grails

Tags: mongodb, rest, grails, grails-orm, objectid

Grails makes it easy to [get](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/get.html) a domain object by ID (handy for building a REST API).

A controller to retrieve a resource can be as simple as:

**MetricController.groovy**

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class MetricController {

   def index() {
      def resource = Metric.get(params.id)
      render resource as JSON
      }

   }
```

When using the Grails plugin for MongoDB GORM (`compile ":mongodb:1.2.0"`), the default `id` type of `Long` [needs to be changed](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/18510469058/grails-in-the-land-of-mongodb) to type `String` or `ObjectId`.

**Metric.groovy**

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId

class Metric {
   static mapWith = "mongo"
   ObjectId id
   String title
   }
```

However, doing a `.get(1)` will now result in:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/bow/rest/metric/1
Class
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Message
invalid ObjectId [1]
```

I took a guess and changed the controller to use `findById`:

```
def resource = Metric.findById(new ObjectId(new Date(), params.id.toInteger()))
```

That fixed the error, but it fails to find the object (always returns null).

For example, using the id of "-1387348672" does not find this test object:

```
{ "class" : "Metric",
  "id" : { "class" : "org.bson.types.ObjectId",
      "inc" : -1387348672,
      "machine" : 805582250,
      "new" : false,
      "time" : 1371329632000,
      "timeSecond" : 1371329632
    },
  "title" : "Test"
}
```

The `ObjectId.inc` field may not even be the correct field to use for the resource ID.

So, what is the simplest way to retrieve a domain object by ID when using MongoDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a domain object is persisted in MongoDB, it is stored as a document with an [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) as a unique 12 bytes BSON primary key. For example, if you have a domain object `Product` like

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId
class Product {
    ObjectId id
    String name

    static mapWith = "mongo"
}
```

then the persisted entity in MongoDB would look like below if you save with a name as "TestProduct".

```
//db.product.find() in mongodb
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("51bd047c892c8bf0b3a58b21"), 
  "name" : "TestProduct", 
  "version" : 0 
}
```

The `_id` becomes your primary key for that document. To `get` this document you need the primary key ObjectId. Speaking from a RESTful context, you atleast need the 12 bytes hexcode `51bd047c892c8bf0b3a58b21` as part of the request.

So in the above case, you can fetch that particular document by doing something like

```
Product.get(new ObjectId("51bd047c892c8bf0b3a58b21"))
Product.findById(new ObjectId("51bd047c892c8bf0b3a58b21"))
```

Have a look at the [API for ObjectId](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/org/bson/types/ObjectId.html) which would make clear how to retrieve a document.

When you retrieve the document as JSON, then it just shows the ObjectId class with its elements.

```
{
    "class": "com.example.Product",
    "id": {
        "class": "org.bson.types.ObjectId",
        "inc": -1280996575,
        "machine": -1993569296,
        "new": false,
        "time": 1371341948000,
        "timeSecond": 1371341948
    },
    "name": "TestProduct"
}
```

Comment: Knowing that the ID should be the 12-byte hex BSON key got me pointed in the right direction.  It turns out to be quite easy to generate ID strings from ObjectIDs... just use `.toString()`.  And then you can pass the ID string directly to `.get()` as long as the ID string is formatted correctly (`[0-9a-f]{24}`).

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, here's the domain with a controller to get a resource by **ID string** (instead of **ObjectID**).

Example:
`Metric.get("51bf8ccc30040460f5a05579")`

**Domain**

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId

class Metric {

   ObjectId id
   String   title

   static mapWith = "mongo"

   def out() {
      return [
         id:    id as String,  //convert Mongo ObjectId to 12-byte hex BSON
         title: title
         ]
      }

   }
```

The `out()` method is used to render the resource showing its ID string (not its ObjectID).

**Controller**

```
import grails.converters.JSON

class MetricController {

   def index() {
      def resource = Metric.read(params.id)
      render resource.out() as JSON
      }

   }
```

**Example JSON response for** `/rest/metric/51bf8ccc30040460f5a05579`

```
{ "id": "51bf8ccc30040460f5a05579", "title": "Accounts" }
```